# How to figure out wire types while replacing old switches with new ones

Tags: wiring

Trying to replace these old switches (1990 build) to new Leviton z-wave switches [DZS15-1BZ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GONGX98).

[The Leviton manual](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibcGetAttachment.jsp?cItemId=uG6NT9SjWaPsKV35Wr.W8A) for new switches expect 3 (BL, WH and RD wires) + 1 ground. But when I opened the old switch, I see 2 BL wires and 1 ground (which is no plugged to the switch).

Now how do I figure out where these 2 BL will go in the new switch?

Old switch:
[image: old switch]

New switch:
[image: new switch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be out of luck. Mechanical switches don't need a neutral. Electronic gizmos generally do.

- The black wire that is permanently hot connects to BK
- The black wire that is switched hot (goes to load e.g. lamp) connects to RD
- The white wire that <strike>is missing</strike> *Connor spotted* connects to WH
- Nothing connects to YL/RD (that is only for 3-way switches).
- A pigtail from the ground wire connects to the green terminal screw.

Worst case: You might need to run new wiring to the switches. That might mean opening up the walls.

Comment: What is the advantage of this new type of switch that requires new wiring? Are the old type still made?

Comment: @Jim. The "advantage" is you can (boast to visitors that you can) turn your lights off in your home while you are eating sushi with the pope in Tokyo at 4 a.m. Yes the old type are still made (mostly badly, in China). I once felt the same way about TV remotes.

Comment: My junction boxes have a lot of the room taken up with pigtail connections to the original 1970 aluminum wiring. I don't think they will accommodate any of these new devices. I saved the original 3-way switches controlling one outside light when I put a timer on it 30 years ago. Now I want to return it to original and have the switches I took out.

Comment: From the first picture, you can see a neutral in the box, so the wiring should be sufficient.  Box fill may be another story however @RedGrittyBrick

Comment: You can buy quality switches, you just have to pay $3-6 for them instead of 74 cents.  Electronic switches are a godsend for "making safe" many unsafe situations and otherwise-unsolvable wiring problems.